# What is the meaning of 'remaining in still'

Tags: meaning

On [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitch#Noun) the entry for the word Pitch is:

> A dark, extremely viscous material **remaining in still** after distilling crude oil and tar.

What exactly does the phrasing 'remaining in still' mean?

Comment: At first sight it looks as though there is a definite article missing and the phrase should be **remaining in _the_ still** (the still being the equipment being used to distill the oil or tar). However I believe that 'in still' could be a technical term in chemical engineering meaning "in the still or whatever equipment or installation is being used to crack the feedstock". I've never worked in an oil refinery or any other chemical engineering environment so I can't be sure and I can't find the term on line so this is posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Wiktionary is to be treated with caution; its entries can be created by anyone (e.g. Harry Hardhat who works in a refinery); it is not an authoritative, edited and checked dictionary, like e.g. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pitch) - "a thick, black substance that was used in the past to make wooden ships and buildings waterproof"